# arranging binary words in circle - induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, binary

i need to prove that for set A which contains all of the binary words of length n can be arranged in a circle so each two adjacent words will be different only by one char.

I tried solving it by induction but i have a hard problem proving that P(k)⟹P(k+1)..

Is induction the right way to prove this? Or should I try to prove it by other techniques?
[for example n=3 looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7TL3.png)

thank you

Comment: These are *Gray codes*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Comment: well how should i go to proof gray code by induction?

Comment: There's a proof in the Wikipedia article....